# "java.lang.ClassCastException: weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistrySAXParserFactory cannot be cast to javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory

Tags: xml, spring, maven, exception, jaxp

I work with Spring MVC, weblogic 10.3.6.

I have a jsp. The taglib declarations are

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>
<%@ page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
```

My project deploys well. When I execute it, I get a exception

```
"java.lang.ClassCastException: weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistrySAXParserFactory cannot be cast to javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory".
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

Maven dependencies tree is

```
[INFO] ecalcpAdmin:ecalcpAdmin:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.1.3)
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.2.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:3.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- (aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.2.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- (aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- taglibs:standard:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO] +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-c3p0:jar:4.1.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.0.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- c3p0:c3p0:jar:0.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- (org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.1.3.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.15:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.1.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- (antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.0.GA:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.15.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |     \- (org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.0.CR2:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.1.0.GA)
[INFO] +- com.oracle:ojdbc6:jar:11.2.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.jasypt:jasypt:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.jasypt:jasypt-spring31:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- (org.jasypt:jasypt:jar:1.9.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.51:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:jar:4.1.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.0.GA:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:jar:2.4.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.6.6)
[INFO] |  \- (org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.1.3.Final:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:2.7.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.6:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.5.10)
[INFO] +- com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.4.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- xmlpull:xmlpull:jar:1.1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- xpp3:xpp3_min:jar:1.1.4c:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.tukaani:xz:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.jsoup:jsoup:jar:1.8.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.mobile:spring-mobile-device:jar:1.1.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.2.13.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.2.6.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.13.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.2.6.RELEASE)
[INFO] +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.0.0.GA:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator-annotation-processor:jar:4.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:4.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |     +- (javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.0.0.GA:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.6:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.6.6)
[INFO] +- edu.vt.middleware:vt-password:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- edu.vt.middleware:vt-dictionary:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- edu.vt.middleware:vt-crypt:jar:2.1.4:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15:jar:1.45:compile
[INFO] |     +- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |     \- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.1.3)
[INFO] +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.7.4:compile
[INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.10:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.10:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:3.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.6.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.10:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.5.10:runtime
[INFO] |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.10:runtime - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.5.10:runtime
[INFO] |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.10:runtime - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- (log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.14:runtime - omitted for conflict with 1.2.15)
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.9.5:test
[INFO] |  +- (org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.1:test - omitted for conflict with 1.3)
[INFO] |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:1.0:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:3.2.6.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.6.RELEASE:test - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1:runtime - omitted for conflict with 1.1.3)
[INFO] |  \- (log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.13:runtime - omitted for conflict with 1.2.15)
[INFO] \- org.owasp.esapi:esapi:jar:2.1.0:compile
[INFO]    +- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO]    |  +- (commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  +- (commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.3:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.1.3)
[INFO]    |  +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  \- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.3:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.1.3)
[INFO]    |  |  \- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.1.3)
[INFO]    |  \- (commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils-core:jar:1.7.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils-core:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.1.3)
[INFO]    |  \- (commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:2.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.2)
[INFO]    +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO]    +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2:compile
[INFO]    +- (log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.16:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.2.15)
[INFO]    +- xom:xom:jar:1.2.5:compile
[INFO]    |  +- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.3.03:compile
[INFO]    |  +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- (xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.3.03:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  \- xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO]    |     \- (xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.3.03)
[INFO]    +- org.beanshell:bsh-core:jar:2.0b4:compile
[INFO]    \- org.owasp.antisamy:antisamy:jar:1.4.3:compile
[INFO]       +- (xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.8.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.8.0)
[INFO]       +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-css:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO]       |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-ext:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO]       |  |  \- (xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.3.04:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.3.03)
[INFO]       |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-util:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO]       |  +- (xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.3.04:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.3.03)
[INFO]       |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis-ext:jar:1.3.04:compile
[INFO]       +- net.sourceforge.nekohtml:nekohtml:jar:1.9.12:compile
[INFO]       |  \- (xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.8.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.8.0)
[INFO]       \- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO]          +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.4:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.1.3)
[INFO]          \- (commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.2:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.5)
```

weblogic.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app
    xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd 
    http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app
     http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.3/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
    <wls:weblogic-version>10.3.6</wls:weblogic-version>
    <wls:context-root>EcalpAdmin</wls:context-root>
    <wls:container-descriptor>
        <wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>true</wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>
    </wls:container-descriptor>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

I dont't know why I get this exception.

EDIT

The difference between my last question and this is the following dependency. I have a new dependency .

```
[INFO] \- org.owasp.esapi:esapi:jar:2.1.0:compile
[INFO]    +- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO]    |  +- (commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  +- (commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.3:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.1.3)
[INFO]    |  +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  \- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.3:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.1.3)
[INFO]    |  |  \- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.1.3)
[INFO]    |  \- (commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils-core:jar:1.7.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils-core:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.1.3)
[INFO]    |  \- (commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:2.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.2)
[INFO]    +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO]    +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2:compile
[INFO]    +- (log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.16:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.2.15)
[INFO]    +- xom:xom:jar:1.2.5:compile
[INFO]    |  +- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.3.03:compile
[INFO]    |  +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- (xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.3.03:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    |  \- xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO]    |     \- (xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.3.03)
[INFO]    +- org.beanshell:bsh-core:jar:2.0b4:compile
[INFO]    \- org.owasp.antisamy:antisamy:jar:1.4.3:compile
[INFO]       +- (xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.8.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.8.0)
[INFO]       +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-css:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO]       |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-ext:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO]       |  |  \- (xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.3.04:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.3.03)
[INFO]       |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-util:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO]       |  +- (xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.3.04:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.3.03)
[INFO]       |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis-ext:jar:1.3.04:compile
[INFO]       +- net.sourceforge.nekohtml:nekohtml:jar:1.9.12:compile
[INFO]       |  \- (xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.8.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.8.0)
[INFO]       \- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO]          +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.4:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.1.3)
[INFO]          \- (commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.2:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.5)
```

Do I have to remove  ?

(xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.3.03:compile - omitted for duplicate)

Thanks
**EDITED (solution)**

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.owasp.esapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>esapi</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
```

Comment: What did you do to fix your other Exception? Comparing both errors, chances are high the culprit is the same. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39073159/weblogic-xml-jaxp-registrydocumentbuilderfactory-cannot-be-cast-to-javax-xml-par

Comment: I edit my question to do a comment

Comment: I fixed the error. I edit the solution